# Activity Back button is not doing anything

Tags: java, android

In my `MainActivity` I have defined:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//      int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_settings:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings menu clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
      case R.id.menu_location:
      startLocationUpdates();
      setupViewPager();
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

The `Settings Activity` is the default `New->Activity->Settings` created by Android studio as:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
      setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is the back button is actually not doing anything, i.e. clicking the back button on SettingsActivity is not taking me to the MainActivity.

What should I do?

Comment: Does it close the app when you hit the back button?

Comment: no, its doing just nothing, except the touch animation. its neither closing, nor going back to main activity

Comment: Did you override onBackButtonPressed anywhere?

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` on your `SettingActivity` and add a breakpoint on `super.onBackPressed()`, check if it calls or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try implementing on `Settings Activity`

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```